# Interpretation of $k$ in $\frac{k^nx}{k^n+x^n}$?

Tags: calculus

I have read the following Expression

$$y=\frac{k^nx}{k^n+x^n}$$

with $k,n>0,\ x\geq 0$.

In the article $k$ has a prominent impact. However, I was asking myself if $k$ has a particular mathematical Interpretation (potentially only on intervals of $n$) in this equation. Such as the inflection point if it exists occurs at $x=k$ - just as an example.

I didn‘t find anything special. Thanks!

Comment: It is the same as $\frac x{1+\left(\frac xk\right)^n}$, maybe this helps?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're looking for as an answer. $k$ is a constant that is part of the definition of $y$. The myriad different aspects of $y$ (inflection point, limits, derivatives, etc.) will depend on $k$ in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$y=\frac{k^nx}{k^n+x^n} = k \frac{(x/k)}{1+(x/k)^n}.$$

so that $k$ has the effect of enlarging the graph of the $k=1$ case by a factor of $k$ (in both $x$ and $y$).  In general if $g(x) = kf(x/k)$ then $g(x)$ is given by  dilating the graph of $f(x)$  a factor of $k$ along both the $x$- and $y$- axes.  That is, the point $(a,b)$ becomes the point $(ka, kb)$: if $f(a) = b$ then $g(ka) = kf(ka/k) = kg(a) = kb$.